# How to convert 16 digit epoch timestamp to datetime in c# without losing microseconds precision

Tags: c#

```
    public static DateTime ToDateTimeForEpochMSec(this double microseconds)
    {
        var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        DateTime tempDate = epoch.AddMilliseconds(microseconds / 1000);
        return tempDate;
    }
```

tried using this code but losing microseconds precison in the datetime

Comment: Show us an example of what your acceptance criteria is and what code didn't work for you

Comment: Well, 1 microsecond would be `TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond / 1000` ticks, so you could add that number of ticks to the unix epoch.

Comment: Is your question still outstanding? Does my answer not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your code to handle microseconds. We know that 1000 microseconds = 1 millisecond, therefore 1/1000th of a millisecond is a microsecond. Now, after `AddMilliseconds`, the next level of precision that `DateTime` supports is `Ticks`, so we'll have to use that.

We can find the number of ticks in a millisecond by using `TimeSpan`:

```
long ticksPerMillisecond = TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
```

If 1 microsecond is 1/1000th of a millisecond, then it stands to reason that we need 1/1000th of the ticks to represent a microsecond. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=net-5.0) defines a tick as:

> one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond (see TicksPerMillisecond) and 10 million ticks in a second.

We should therefore be safe to use integer division to divide by 1000:

```
long ticksPerMicrosecond = TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond / 1000;
```

Now we can convert the number of microseconds into ticks:

```
long ticks = (long)(microseconds * ticksPerMicrosecond);
```

And add it to the epoch:

```
DateTime tempDate = epoch.AddTicks(ticks);
```

Putting it all together we get:

```
public static DateTime ToDateTimeForEpochMSec(this double microseconds)
{
    var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    long ticksPerMicrosecond = TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond / 1000;
    long ticks = (long)(microseconds * ticksPerMicrosecond);
    DateTime tempDate = epoch.AddTicks(ticks);
    return tempDate;
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/SFFA47971)

By the way, I'm not sure why microseconds is a `double` here. It seems like it would be fine as a `long`.